# OpenCV jpeg format image in memory

Tags: c++, opencv

Is there a possibility of saving an image to a string instead of a file with OpenCV?

I have found just this function in  the docs:

```
int cvSaveImage(const char* filename, const CvArr* image)
```

And it can only save to files.

Comment: What do you mean by saving an image as a string?

Comment: I mean do not save to file but save to char* variable instead, for example.

Comment: You could use the JPEG library to compress imageData.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How did you want to code the image in the string?
You could just store red,green,blue values as comma separated strings but coding the image binary as something like base64 would be more compact.

Edit: if you mean a jpeq format in memory see - [OpenCV to use in memory buffers or file pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/801199/opencv-to-use-in-memory-buffers-or-file-pointers)

Comment: Well, I want image saved as JPEG but not to file but to string.

Comment: I know I could save it to file and then load it from that file but I don't want to store the image at all. I want to send it over wifi to another PC.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/801199/opencv-to-use-in-memory-buffers-or-file-pointers

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can simply create a char* buffer and copy your IplImage data structure there ?
But be careful, you should carefully copy the pointer variables, such as `imageData`, `imageDataOrigin` and so on.

So the idea is to put everything in your buffer in the way you can decode it from the receiver's side.

And opencv is an opensource library and you can simply copy the opencv's savefile function body, replacing writing in a file to writing in your buffer

Comment: I have either a BGR image in my buffer and I want to transform it into a JPEG.