# Convert Mat image into a JPG without using CvSaveImage in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

I wish to convert a mat image into a JPG image in the memory. I know I can use CvSaveImage for this, that creates a jpg file, I read it again and then stream it over the network. I wish to avoid this extra disk write-read operation. If you have any ideas, it would really help. There's a similar question on StackOverflow, but they ask how in C#, I need assistance with the C++ openCV library.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/801199/opencv-to-use-in-memory-buffers-or-file-pointers

Answer (score 4):

[imencode/imdecode](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#imdecode)

---

(and again, CvSaveImage is C, not C++. avoid the whole outdated opencv C api, if you can. there' ll be no support for it in the near future)

Comment: But this does not code it to jpg...

Comment: it encodes to a *memory buffer* of a png/jpeg