# Convert ushort image to binary?

Tags: c#, image

I have an image in ushort variable, want to save this image in binary format.

Please, anyone, tell me How can this be done using C#?

I have tried this but its not working

```
ushort[] Depthdata;
Depthdata = new ushort[DWidth * DHeight];
string s1 = string.Format("{0}", count_depth);
FileStream fs = new FileStream("C:\\img" + s1 + ".bin", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fs);
string image_str = Convert.ToString(Imagedata);
bw.Write(image_str);
bw.Close();
fs.Close();
```

Here is attached my full [code](https://www.dropbox.com/s/w2joodgc2cj4dta/Code_Cam.txt?dl=0)

Comment: for giving -1 please explain the reason so i can update or check whats wrong i am doing

Comment: @Addee, your image must be quite small if it can fit in a `ushort`. Could it be an array of `ushort` instead?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: The definition of Depthdata is like this `ushort[] Depthdata;` `Depthdata = new ushort[DWidth * DHeight];`

Comment: That's an array, then. You probably should update your question with that information.

Comment: Ok, I have updated the question. do you have any solution for this?

Comment: I'm still trying to understand why you're calling `Convert.ToString()` on that data...

Comment: Actually, I just did that because it was showing me error when I do  `bw.Write(Imagedata);` so I used that to convert to string. but I am not sure it is correct or not

Comment: Do you have an `Image` or `Bitmap` built in your code anywhere?  It would be easier to save that.  Otherwise do you have a **format** that the data should be saved in?

Comment: @Idle_Mind, i modified my post and added my full code to check.
i want to save in .bin format, which will later used in MATLAB for further processing

Comment: I have no idea what format MATLAB expects.  That's a pretty important piece of information you should have included in your problem description.

Comment: Why did you want to use a .bin extension for an image? That's very uncommon, and looking at [MATLAB supported import formats](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/supported-file-formats.html), it looks like it doesn't even support .bins for import...

Comment: @DylanCorriveau: I can save the image in (.png, .gif, .tif) but that took much in saving the image and there is a stream of image coming at 30fps. So I decided to save in .bin format which take less time save

Comment: @Addee, since you are not really interested in the data as an image but rather as a matrix, I recommend you use the `.MAT` format. It's text-based and thus a bit easier to handle in my opinion.

Comment: @Abbondanza Can you please tell me the code how can save `Imagedata` variable to `Mat` in c#?

Comment: @Addee for .mat files, take a look [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/98947-is-it-possible-to-read-write-mat-files-from-a-c-application)

Answer (score 1):

I would like to mention that the code here, and the one in your link are different...

In any case, going by the one in your link:

```
ushort[] Depthdata;
....
string s1 = string.Format("{0}", count_depth);
FileStream fs = new FileStream("G:\\test" + s1 + ".bin", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fs);
string depth_str = Convert.ToString(Depthdata);
bw.Write(depth_str);
bw.Close();
fs.Close();
```

You shouldn't actually need to convert your Depthdata to a string. BinaryWriter can actually take a [ushort value](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8sh9zw1e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in one of its overloads. Why not just iterate through and write it out? Also, you should use [using statements](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) for your filestream and binarywriter.

Try the following:

```
using(FileStream fs = new FileStream("G:\\test" + s1 + ".bin", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
{
    using(BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fs))
    {
        foreach(ushort value in Depthdata)
        {
            bw.write(value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In case how can i use `IplImage` instead of `ushort`?

Comment: `IplImage` has a method called `ToBitmap()`, just use that, then use .Save (filename). You won't need to use what i wrote if you are using that...

Comment: can you tell me the extact code for that? and can i save the `IplImage` to .bin also?

Comment: There's a nice explanation found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/697801/convert-iplimage-into-a-jpeg-without-using-cvsaveimage-in-opencv)

Answer (score 1):

I think this will help you.i tested this on *.tiff file

first make separate Class **Ext**

```
public static class Ext
    {

        public static string ToHexString(this byte[] hex)
        {
            if (hex == null) return null;
            if (hex.Length == 0) return string.Empty;

            var s = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (byte b in hex)
            {
                s.Append(b.ToString("x2"));
            }
            return s.ToString().ToUpper();
        }
    }
```

then you can Add following code to convert image to string binary

```
 FileStream fs=new FileStream(ImgPathID, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read); //set file stream
 Byte[] bindata=new byte[Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length)];
 fs.Read(bindata, 0, Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length));
string  bindatastring = Ext.ToHexString(bindata);// call to class
```